# Is there an ETF or Mutual Fund which tracks James O'Shaugnessy's Trending 25 stock strategy?

Tags: mutual-funds, etf

The strategy is described here: http://www.valuestockscreener.com/Screens/Details/OShaughnessy_Trending_Value

I've found 5 mutual funds at O'Shaugnessy's asset management website (www.osfunds.com) but none of them seem to track the  Trending Value strategy. I also learned that O'Shaugnessy sold 2 of his funds to Hennessy Funds (https://www.cxoadvisory.com/2713/fundamental-valuation/out-of-sample-test-of-what-works-on-wall-street-oshaughnessys-cornerstone-strategies/). But again these don't seem to fully reflect Trending Value.

Answer (score 1):

Funds can't limit themselves to a small number of stocks without also limiting themselves to a small amount of total investment. I think 25 companies is too small to be practical from their point of view.

Comment: But aren't there funds that track the Dow Jones Industrial Average (30 stocks)? I remember one fund that claimed to track the "Dogs of the Dow" index which would presumably have fewer than 25 funds...